# How to check if my video is decodable using OpenImaj?

Tags: java, video, decoding, openimaj

I'm using the OpenImaj library in Java for my project and i would like to know if there is a way to check if a video is decodable when opened with XuggleVideo ?
Because i need to create my own exception class in my project and to do that i need to check if the video is correctly opened.

I tried looking in OpenImaj's API but i didn't found anything.

Do you know if it's possible ?
Thanks !

Comment: You can check the number of frames to ensure the vidoe is correclty opened using countFrames method from the [docs](http://openimaj.org/apidocs/index.html).  The value returned from the method must be greater than zero.

Comment: Yeah it does perfectly the job ! Thank you :)